# Database changing for .net application

Tags: asp.net, oracle9i

i m having two databases in different environments but both are having same data.Presently my application  connecting one database .I need to disconnect that database and i want to connect another database .Is it possible to connect to another database? If Its possible then what are things i have to modify in the application code.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? Where is/are the connection strings stored?

Comment: We are trying to do currently which database is using for application that database is removing and one more database is adding.

Comment: What type of database is it? SQL-Server? If so, which versions are they (both the one you've got now and the one you're now trying to connect to).

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to connect to another database?

Yes.

> If it is possible then what are things I have to modify in the application code.

You need to change the Data provider APIs especially if you are working with the database specific API e.g Ms-Sql server (SqlClient) or ODP.net (oracle).

For further, read - [Data Access Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648175.aspx) and .[NET Data Access Architecture Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817654.aspx).